# Calculate visibility with polygonal visual barriers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst, visibility

I have the raster file for my digitial elevation model as well as a polygon shapefile with polygons representing different kinds of environments (forest, field, meadow, etc), and wouldlike to calculate the surface of the visible area from several points while taking into account both elevation and environment type - for example, forest polygons should be visual barriers as it is not possible to see anything through forests. But there isn't such an option in the Visibility tool.

I already tried to calculate visibility within a donut raster which forest polygons are removed from. The good point is that forests themselves are not counted as visible when calculating the visible area, but the problem is that with this method they are considered transparent (as usual with no data cells...), and the area right behind them is always considered visible, which is the opposite of what I wanted...

Does someone know how to do this ? I use both Python and the user interface, but prefer Python.

I was also considering the creation of a local raster with higher raster elevation values where the forest polygons are, or to assign a very high elevation to all cells with no elevation data (which would make them visual barriers) but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Your idea of modifying the elevations is an effective one.  (It can even be extended to allow for random variation in heights within each environment and even partial transparency if you wish.)  For how to make the modifications, search our site for [con](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=con).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to add an attribute to your polygon layer, say "VALUE", and assign it numeric value of 1000 or more. Then convert the polygon layer to a raster. In arcpy using the spatial analyst module these rasters can be multiplied easily.

```
elevRast = arcpy.Raster("path/elevrast")
polyRast = arcpy.Raster("path/polygonraster")
resultRast = elevRast*polyrast
```

Ideally, if the polygon raster has nodata for anything outside of the polygon, the resultRast should have elevation in the forested area that is a 1000 times higher than the surrounding areas. You can also use a value of 1 to get the equivalent elevation if your polygon areas don't need to exaggerate the elevation.

You can put these directly into the geoprcesses as well.

Either the visibility http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000zr000000:

```
outvis = arcpy.sa.Visibility(resultRast, inObserverFeatures, algOutput, analysisType,
                            nonVisibleValue, zFactor, useEarthCurvature,
                            refractivityCoefficient, surfaceOffset, observerElevation,
                            observerOffset, innerRadius, outerRadius, horizStartAngle,
                            horizEndAngle, vertUpperAngle, vertLowerAngle)

# Save the output
outvis.save("c:/sapyexamples/output/visiout1")
```

or viewshed http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000v3000000:

```
outViewshed = arcpy.sa.Viewshed(resultRast, inObserverFeatures, zFactor, 
                       useEarthCurvature, refractivityCoefficient)
# Save the output 
outViewshed.save("C:/sapyexamples/output/outvwshd02")
```

Comment: This multiplication will be ineffective for two reasons.  First, at locations away from sea level your forested areas will rise many kilometers into the sky, which is obviously unrealistic. Second, near sea level they will be too short.  Why not just *add* a typical tree height to the DEM in forested areas?

Comment: Good points. I think in the end it depends on the region under study and the observation point locations. I used an unrealistic elevation on purpose because the OP wanted to exclude the forest areas and the areas behind them which this would certainly do. I could see a problem with sea level if the observation point was at an elevation that was above 1000. Tree height would be another option, but the technique is the same (addition maybe instead of multiplication).

Comment: The problem is that this does not "exclude" the forest areas. On the contrary, your approach causes them to block all lines of sight that pass through any forested area.  It seems unlikely that such behavior would be intended in any application.

Comment: @whuber Maybe I'm reading the OP question differently? I interpret the sentence in the second paragraph beginning with "The good point..." as they do want to block the line of sight. I don't understand how it does not "exclude" the forest since the cells within the polygon now (theoretically) sit above the height of the observation point and are no longer visible. The height of the cells, as you say, block the line of sight and would cause the areas beyond the forest to not be visible, which I think is what the OP wanted...

Comment: @whuber sorry ran out of characters. Could you post an answer with your method? I think it would be quite useful to see an alternative solution that may be better generally.